# Lectura de registros de un medidor

Tags: python, modbus

estoy tratando de leer los registros de memoria de un medidor modbus TCP con Python.
Tengo el medidor conectado a una raspberry con un modem SIM7600E que lleva una SIM, que es la que me da la IP privada. Con eso he montado un servidor modbus y desde otros programas no tengo problemas en conectarme y acceder al medidor.

Este es el código que estoy usando

```
import time
from pyModbusTCP.client import ModbusClient


# init modbus client
c = ModbusClient(host='10.79.253.201', port= 502, auto_close= False, auto_open= True, debug= True)

# main read loop
while True:
    # read 10 registers at address 0, store result in regs list
    regs_l = c.read_input_registers(0, 10)

    # if success display registers
    if regs_l:
        print('reg ad #0 to 9: %s' % regs_l)
    else:
        print('unable to read registers')

    # sleep 2s before next polling
    time.sleep(2)
```

Y este es el error que me da

```
Tx
[56 44 00 00 00 06 01] 04 00 00 00 0A
Rx
[56 44 00 00 00 03 01] 84 0B
modbus exception (code 11 "gateway target device failed to respond")
unable to read registers
```

He hecho varias pruebas y no tengo problema al conectarme al servidor modbus pero a la hora de acceder a los registros me da fallo. Estoy pasándome algo por alto?

Comment: te da el fallo siempre o funciona unas cuantas iteraciones y al cabo de un rato deja de funcionar?

Comment: Me da el fallo siempre